# SP2010 Content Deployment error "Ignoring the current item since it cannot be imported."

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-deployment, bug

I have a problem while I referenced a page(A) to another page(B) with "a href" tag inside PublishingPageContent field. If I checkout page(B) (save as draft) and start it dep. manually... I faced

> "Ignoring the current item since it cannot be imported - pages/test.aspx"

This bug broke versioning and sometimes referenced pages taken from published to draft

I look at dep logs but no explanation.
Anybody faced with this problem or bug?
Thanks for the help.